# componentWillReceiveProps not firing on props update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react 15 and react-router 4. Container is connected with react-router, and the `url` parameter changes on each request, then the `currentUrl` prop is updated in the Sidebar component. This is caught locally on Sidebar.js and stored in local state (which is necessary for more actions). However, `componentWillReceiveProps()` is only called several times on initial renders, and does not fire if the user navigates after that.

**Container.js**

```
class Container extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const { match: { url } } = this.props;

        return (
            <Sidebar
              currentUrl={url}/>
         );
    }
}

export default SidebarContainer = withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(Container));
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { currentUrl } = nextProps;

    this.setState({
      // calculations on currentUrl
    });
}

render() {
    const { currentUrl } = this.props;

    return <div></div> // view
}
```

The architecture of the components follows the [React Router's sidebar example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar).

Comment: there is no equivalent method for the state as state changes should never trigger any props changes. http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

Comment: @Khun However, the prop (currentUrl) does change. `setState` is only called within `componentWillReceiveProps`, which in return correctly does not trigger another `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: In case I am not clear, the `currentUrl` of `Container` does change and the prop does update in `Sidebar`, as observed in `render()`.

Comment: right before render() put console.log(url) and tell me if you can see it?

Comment: Do you mean in `componentWillUpdate`?

Comment: put a demo on codepen or something, please value others time

Comment: The code is quite similar to the [react-router's sidebar](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

The react router renders each route again on every url change, because it belongs inside the route as a different subcomponent. Thus, `render()` functions (and the component's `constructor`) were fired normally since the component was mounted again. However, `componentWillReceiveProps` only fires after the initial render of the component. So far it fired because some props were updated without changing the current location (other props of the `Sidebar` component).

My work around was to calculate some logic in the `constructor` (to reduce some load) and the rest on `render()`, avoiding state.